# How can I check if all tasks have been completed (normally or abruptly)?

Tags: java, multithreading, threadpoolexecutor

I have the following class:

```
public class Service{
    private static final ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(4);

    public synchronized void execute(Collection<Runnable> runs){
        for(Runnable r: runs){
            executor.execute(r);
        }
    }

    public boolean isComplete(){
        //should return true iff all tasks applied by the execute(Collection<Runnable> runs) 
        //method're finished their execution (normally or abruptly, 
        //it doesn matter)
    }
}
```

How can I implement the `isComplete()` method. I need to check if there's a task that is currently in progress. If the executor is cleared(all tasks are completed) then the method should return true, otherwise return false.

Comment: Is there any reason that `execute` is synchronized in your code sample?

Comment: @AndyBrown In the code I presenten, no there isn't. But I intended to use it in the following way: Once the executor start executing a task it's impossible for any other thread to call the execute method until all `Runnable`s are finished.

Comment: That implies you might re-use a `Service`. I would be tempted not to as it is so lightweight - just make it so it allows single submission only, and then is dropped after it completes. Otherwise you are going to have services that are not complete, then are complete, then are not complete, ... - and that will potentially cause problems.

Comment: @AndyBrown The thing is `Service` has the `Application Scope`, so I don't think that I will end up with incomplete service....

Comment: I have the strong feeling that you are reinventing [`invokeAll`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html#invokeAll-java.util.Collection-)…

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Given that you are using `ExecutorService` you could use [`submit`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html#submit-java.lang.Runnable-) instead of `execute` and store the returned `Future` in a list. Then inside `isComplete()` iterate through all of the `Future`s and call `isDone()` on each one. (This approach will also let you cancel the submitted tasks if required, through the `Future`s).

For example <sup>†</sup> :

```
class Service{
    private static final ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(4);
    private List<Future<?>> futures;
    public void execute(Collection<Runnable> runs){
        futures = runs.stream()
                .map(r -> executor.submit(r))
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
    }

    public boolean isComplete(){
        for (Future<?> future : futures) 
            if (!future.isDone()) return false;

        return true;
    }
}
```

Depending on your use case, you may get better performance by removing items from the `futures` list as you go, but you (may) need to sync the `isComplete` method:

```
    public synchronized boolean isComplete(){
        Iterator<Future<?>> itr = futures.iterator();
        while (itr.hasNext()) {
            if (itr.next().isDone()) itr.remove();
            else return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
```

<sup>†</sup> *As this code sample is written, it assumes that you will only make one call to `execute` per instance of `Service`, so it does not need to be `synchronized`. If you will have multiple concurrent callers to `execute` on each `Service` instance then note that this will replace the `futures` list on each call to `execute`. You could handle that by making the class single-use only, or by appending to futures. It depends entirely on your use-case.*

Comment: I was writing this same code but you posted it sooner. I was wondering if `isComplete` should be synchronized though. By the way, you need to use an `Iterator`, otherwise `futures.remove` is going to throw an `ConcurrentModificationException`.

Comment: Good advice, thank you. BTW, is it correct to wrap the `List<Future<?>>` into a single `Future<?>`. The question is not directly related to what I asked though...

Comment: @St.Antario - interesting. Conceptually  a `Future` represents ["*the result of an asynchronous computation*"](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Future.html). You could argue that you could break this into smaller async tasks (similar to the `ForkJoinPool`) and so, yes, related `Future`s could be wrapped into a single `Future`.

Answer (score 3):

You can call the `shutdown()` method to ask the executor to terminate all threads and shutdown the pool. And then call `isTerminated()` which will return true if all threads are terminated.

If you want to block execution, you can use the `awaitTerminationMethod()`, and finally `shutDownNow()` will terminate the pool regardless if the threads have completed execution or not.

Comment: The `executor` is a class variable, so is presumably shared across many services in order to provide a common thread pool. Calling `shutdown()` will kill it for all `Service` instances, not just the one that `isComplete()` is called on.

Comment: How about using a **CompletionService** wrapped around the Executor to handle Futures properly then ?

Comment: I like `CompletionService` - it is much overlooked, but it would require a bit of shoe-horning to get it to work here?

Answer (score 2):

**CountDownLatch solved my problem.**

```
ExecutorService WORKER_THREAD_POOL 
  = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10);
CountDownLatch latch = new CountDownLatch(2);
for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
    WORKER_THREAD_POOL.submit(() -> {
        try {
            // ...
            latch.countDown();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
        }
    });
}
 
// wait for the latch to be decremented by the two remaining threads
latch.await();
```